# How to pass an instance of a structure that has implemented a certain trait?

Tags: rust

I am trying to write a correct signature for a method that takes an object by reference as input. It's supposed the object to be an instance of a structure that implements a certain trait.

```
impl MyStruct {
    pub fn create_proof<E: Engine>(&self, C: &Circuit<E>, pk: &Parameters<E>) -> Proof<E> {
        unimplemented!()
    }
}
```

`Circuit` is defined as a trait like this `trait Circuit<E: Engine>` and it has an implemented method inside.

When I compile the project I get the error:

```
the trait `mylib::Circuit` cannot be made into an object
note: method `circuit_method` has generic type parameters
```

Why this error occurred and how to fix it? I am not allowed to modify everything bound to `mylib` where the trait `Circuit` is. All I am allowed to do to write the correct signature. The whole code of the project is too huge and tricky, I do not think it is a good idea to share it.

Comment: Please review how to create a [MCVE] and then [edit] your question to include it. We cannot tell what crates, types, traits, fields, etc. are present in the code. For example, `MyStruct`, `Engine`, `Parameters`, and `Proof` are all undefined. If they aren't needed to reproduce the problem, remove them. Otherwise, minimize them and provide them. Try to produce something that reproduces your error on the [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org) or you can reproduce it in a brand new Cargo project. There are [Rust-specific MCVE tips](//stackoverflow.com/tags/rust/info) as well.

Comment: @Shepmaster Thank you for the information. But I find my question is clear enough to be understood and answered. Short and evident question is better than full and complicated one. As the result, I got quick and satisfied answer. No need to overcharge Stackoverflow.

Comment: @Formalhaut Please do not rollback the edits, because they were made for a reason, e.g. `...` is not valid rust code and is not needed (why bother using the dots, when leaving them out is okay as well). Second it is okay to write `// ...` as method content, but `unimplemented!()` is exactly for this purpose. Next the `<!-- language: none -->` tag is also there for a certain reason. Please avoid rolling back again.

Comment: @hellow After this comment I'd assume you know exactly how the `<!-- language -->` tags work - and that is `none` takes the language(s) assigned to the [tag:none] tag, while `lang-none` takes the language _none_ which is probably exactly what you want in this case

Comment: @msrd0 you're right, but since the [tag:none] has no syntax highlighting it will do the same as `lang-none`. Technically you're right. Feel free to correct the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to make the struct that implements `Circuit` a generic type as well:

```
pub fn create_proof<C, E>(&self, c: &C, pk: &Parameters<E>) -> Proof<E>
where
    C: Circuit<E>,
    E: Engine,
{
    unimplemented!()
}
```